# Octave - how to operate with big numbers

Tags: numbers, octave

I work on RSA algorithm in octave, but it isn't working in proper way. Problem appears while i try to use "^" function. Check my example below:

```
>> mod((80^65), 133)
```

terminal gives me:

```
ans = 0
```

I cannot fix this stuff, it's funny becouse even my system calculator return correct number (54)

Comment: Matlab say the answer is `50`... I would guess the number is larger than the max for double precision

Comment: Try this from the file exchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic

Comment: Dan, thx for your help. I fixed my problem in other way becouse, i don't need result of '^' operation -  i want result of modulo, so i write fast power-modulo algorithm

Comment: Then please add your code as an answer to the question in case people in the future need it.

Answer (score 4):

to calculate this in correct way you can use fast power-modulo algorithm.
In c++, check function below where ->
a^b mod m:

```
int power_modulo_fast(int a, int b, int m)
{
int i;
int result = 1;
int x = a % m;

for (i=1; i<=b; i<<=1)
{
  x %= m;

    if ((b&i) != 0)
      {
    result *= x;
    result %= m;
      }

   x *= x;
}

  return result;
}
```